# How to create a circular ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

How could I create a rounded `ImageView` in Android?

I have tried the following code, but it's not working fine.

Code:

```
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader (bitmap,  TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setShader(shader);

Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint);

imageView.setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
```

Image inside the circle:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: this code may help you. Edit it according  to your needs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/2021499

Comment: @IceMAN i dont want to make rounded corners i need to set image inside circle

Comment: @D'yerMak'er thanks but i want to set the image in circle imageview

Comment: Your post title reads **rounded!!**

Comment: @IceMAN yes.. i have attached the image what i need to do..could you help me out

Comment: Just use the CircularImageView Library "https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView" and its working like a charm in my case

Comment: i have done this using the answer below but different logic see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871833/making-an-image-circular-with-white-circular-border/32346187#32346187

Comment: Nowadays the preferred solution should be **[RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26471808/56285)**; it's nice and simple, and part of official support libs (since v4 Support Library revision 21).

Comment: Nowadays Material Design 1.2.0 introduced **[ShapeableImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66138001/imageview-with-only-bottom-or-top-corners-rounded/66138444#66138444)**.

Answer (score 432, accepted):

I too needed a rounded ImageView, I used the below code, you can modify it accordingly:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        int w = getWidth();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int h = getHeight();

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                    (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor),
                    (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final String color = "#BAB399";
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: is it working fine Permita

Comment: Permita thanks ,i have tried your code, it shows oval imageview, do you know how could i make it rounded with border ,anyway i accept your answer,if you have any idea to make perfect circular image view then kindly help me ....

Comment: What is package name of "ImageUtils"? I cannot find it and IDE made it red :(

Comment: thats a custom package and a custom method for innershadow. I didnt mentioned about it as it was not asked in the question.

Comment: Sorry if I am accidentally bumping an old post, but I would like the code for the drop shadow and the white outline if possible

Comment: @Permita i have some clarification regarding this question can you help me..

Comment: @Permita while i m getting the image from gallery it not getting rounded..but from camera the image is getting rounded..any idea..

Comment: priya can you add your code?

Comment: Hi Permita, I am looking for a library or a solution on how to add the white border to the rounded final image, so exactly the function that you are referring in the line `ImageUtils.setCircularInnerGlow()`. Can you recommend a library for that or share some code please?

Comment: this view is great but it distort not-square images, I fix that here:
https://gist.github.com/melanke/7158342

Comment: The image is having black background after rounding, I tried to change it to some other color, but was not able to do, any help ????

Comment: I was able to use @melanke's gist with NetworkImageView from Volley.

Comment: @Permita Don't do too much of work in `onDraw()` callback as it is called for many times as screen updates!!!

Comment: This may cause OOM due to onDraw() execute to many times.When create a large circular image say 200*200(dip) in tab. So Use a image loader libraries to load a circle a image. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners/23885808#23885808

Comment: A little correction: Insert in the onDraw method after get the bitmap.

if(b == null) return;

Comment: Please tell me how to use the above code for Rounded ImageView. Any example line of code to implement it.

Comment: I've noticed that Google has "RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory" . I think it can be useful.

Comment: @melanke: The code is pretty good. One problem for me is the round circle always is on the left side of the original image. Do you have an idea to get the view-circle in center?

Comment: i have a problem! i am using this as an custom view in a grid view. the `b` variable in `b.copy(...)` is null some time. what?

Comment: Is it just me or does the code mix radius and diameter? So, in some places radius is needed (drawCircle), but when setting the bitmap dimensions, the diameter should be used, not the radius.

Comment: Just use the CircularImageView Library "https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView" and its working like a charm in my case

Comment: What is the point of adding 0.7f and 0.1f? That resulted in the bottom of my images being slightly cut off. Removing them fixed the problem.

Comment: May I suggest: 
  Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w < h ? w : h); So that if the imageview isn't square it always shows the entire image.

Comment: Upvoted. Works awesome, just wanted to point out the variable name 'radius' in the method 'getCroppedBitmap' should be diameter.

Comment: During onDraw is a bad idea. I'd suggest to override setImageDrawable or setImageBitmap and do the calculation there since it's called only once.

Comment: @RudyRudolf So you suggest making the canva a field of the class then ?

Comment: @Ced here is gist from my project. https://gist.github.com/pjakubczyk/5dc2e95739286e2ce186 :)

Comment: @Permita could you update your snippet for better performance?

Comment: The type AvoidXfermode.Mode is deprecated

Comment: to center the image I instead of rectangle version at the end do: if (w>h) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, -(w-h) / 2, 0, paint);
        } else if (w=<h) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, 0, -(h-w) / 2, paint);

Comment: It seems that the issue with this method is that if the CustomImageView have a dynamic image affectation, it will not work. Let's say I create my object. The onDraw method called, the Drawable is null. Then, I assign to my object a Drawable with the setBackground() method. The onDraw is not called again (verified with debugger)

Comment: @Permita Your custom class cause of resize image, see this image http://rupload.ir/upload/y73c1pt579y8uj6xu8ua.png

Comment: why is `int w = getWidth();` returning a value which is 3 times my `layout_width` ? as a result the rounded imageview is getting larger than the layout_width and the image is getting zoomed

Comment: please use this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986850/9802543