# Rounded ImageView scale type

Tags: android, image, scale

I have used Rounded Imageview component using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16208365/1367157)

Now what i want is, i want to set image scale type in this compenent. I tried center,centercrop,fitxy etc..But image is not cropping or setting according to scale type.

Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the code from [this link](https://github.com/makeramen/RoundedImageView) is better ?

as far as i know, it's even better in terms of memory usage.

here's the code:

**RoundedImageView.java**

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
    // based on https://github.com/makeramen/RoundedImageView
    public static final String TAG = "RoundedImageView";

    public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private int mCornerRadius;
    private int mBorderWidth;
    private int mBorderColor;

    private boolean roundBackground;

    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

    private ScaleType mScaleType;

    private static final ScaleType[] sScaleTypeArray = { ScaleType.MATRIX, ScaleType.FIT_XY, ScaleType.FIT_START,
            ScaleType.FIT_CENTER, ScaleType.FIT_END, ScaleType.CENTER, ScaleType.CENTER_CROP, ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE };

    public RoundedImageView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
        mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
        mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER;
        mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    }

    public RoundedImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageView, defStyle, 0);

        final int index = a.getInt(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_android_scaleType, -1);
        if (index >= 0) {
            setScaleType(sScaleTypeArray[index]);
        }

        mCornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_corner_radius, -1);
        mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_width, -1);

        // don't allow negative values for radius and border
        if (mCornerRadius < 0) {
            mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
        }
        if (mBorderWidth < 0) {
            mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER;
        }

        mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);

        roundBackground = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_round_background, false);

        a.recycle();
    }

    /**
     * Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageView.
     * 
     * @param scaleType
     *            The desired scaling mode.
     * 
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
     */
    @Override
    public void setScaleType(final ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
            mScaleType = scaleType;

            switch (scaleType) {
            case CENTER:
            case CENTER_CROP:
            case CENTER_INSIDE:
            case FIT_CENTER:
            case FIT_START:
            case FIT_END:
            case FIT_XY:
                super.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                break;
            default:
                super.setScaleType(scaleType);
                break;
            }

            if (mDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable && ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).getScaleType() != scaleType) {
                ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setScaleType(scaleType);
            }

            if (mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable
                    && ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).getScaleType() != scaleType) {
                ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setScaleType(scaleType);
            }
            setWillNotCacheDrawing(true);
            requestLayout();
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the current scale type in use by this ImageView.
     * 
     * @see ImageView.ScaleType
     * 
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
     */
    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return mScaleType;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(final Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(drawable, mCornerRadius, mBorderWidth, mBorderColor);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setScaleType(mScaleType);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderWidth(mBorderWidth);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
        } else {
            mDrawable = null;
        }
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(final Bitmap bm) {
        if (bm != null) {
            mDrawable = new RoundedDrawable(bm, mCornerRadius, mBorderWidth, mBorderColor);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setScaleType(mScaleType);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderWidth(mBorderWidth);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
        } else {
            mDrawable = null;
        }
        super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }

    // @Override
    // public void setBackground(final Drawable background) {
    // setBackgroundDrawable(background);
    // }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(final Drawable background) {
        if (roundBackground && background != null) {
            mBackgroundDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(background, mCornerRadius, mBorderWidth, mBorderColor);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setScaleType(mScaleType);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderWidth(mBorderWidth);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
        } else {
            mBackgroundDrawable = background;
        }
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
    }

    public int getCornerRadius() {
        return mCornerRadius;
    }

    public int getBorder() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(final int radius) {
        if (mCornerRadius == radius) {
            return;
        }

        this.mCornerRadius = radius;
        if (mDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setCornerRadius(radius);
        }
        if (roundBackground && mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setCornerRadius(radius);
        }
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(final int width) {
        if (mBorderWidth == width) {
            return;
        }

        this.mBorderWidth = width;
        if (mDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderWidth(width);
        }
        if (roundBackground && mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderWidth(width);
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(final int color) {
        if (mBorderColor == color) {
            return;
        }

        this.mBorderColor = color;
        if (mDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mDrawable).setBorderColor(color);
        }
        if (roundBackground && mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderColor(color);
        }
        if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public boolean isRoundBackground() {
        return roundBackground;
    }

    public void setRoundBackground(final boolean roundBackground) {
        if (this.roundBackground == roundBackground) {
            return;
        }

        this.roundBackground = roundBackground;
        if (roundBackground) {
            if (mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
                ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setScaleType(mScaleType);
                ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setCornerRadius(mCornerRadius);
                ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderWidth(mBorderWidth);
                ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderColor(mBorderColor);
            } else {
                setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
            }
        } else if (mBackgroundDrawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setBorderWidth(0);
            ((RoundedDrawable) mBackgroundDrawable).setCornerRadius(0);
        }

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**RoundedDrawable.java**

```
public class RoundedDrawable extends Drawable {

    public static final String TAG = "RoundedDrawable";
    public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

    private final RectF mBounds = new RectF();
    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBitmapRect = new RectF();
    private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint;
    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();

    private float mCornerRadius = 0;
    private boolean mOval = false;
    private float mBorderWidth = 0;
    private ColorStateList mBorderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    private ScaleType mScaleType = ScaleType.FIT_XY;

    public RoundedDrawable(final Bitmap bitmap) {

        mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        mBitmapRect.set(0, 0, mBitmapWidth, mBitmapHeight);

        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);

        mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
        mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(), DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(final Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap;
        final int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        final int height = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
            final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    public static Drawable fromDrawable(final Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            if (drawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
                // just return if it's already a RoundedDrawable
                return drawable;
            } else if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
                // FIXME we don't support ColorDrawables yet
                return drawable;
            } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
                final LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
                final int num = ld.getNumberOfLayers();

                // loop through layers to and change to RoundedDrawables if possible
                for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                    final Drawable d = ld.getDrawable(i);
                    ld.setDrawableByLayerId(ld.getId(i), fromDrawable(d));
                }
                return ld;
            }

            // try to get a bitmap from the drawable and
            final Bitmap bm = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
            if (bm != null) {
                return new RoundedDrawable(bm);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create bitmap from drawable!");
            }
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return mBorderColor.isStateful();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(final int[] state) {
        final int newColor = mBorderColor.getColorForState(state, 0);
        if (mBorderPaint.getColor() != newColor) {
            mBorderPaint.setColor(newColor);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onStateChange(state);
        }
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
        mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
        mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height()
                - mBorderWidth);

        float scale;
        float dx;
        float dy;

        switch (mScaleType) {
        case CENTER:
            mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height()
                    - mBorderWidth);

            mShaderMatrix.set(null);
            mShaderMatrix.setTranslate((int) ((mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth) * 0.5f + 0.5f),
                    (int) ((mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight) * 0.5f + 0.5f));
            break;
        case CENTER_CROP:
            mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height()
                    - mBorderWidth);

            mShaderMatrix.set(null);

            dx = 0;
            dy = 0;

            if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
                scale = mDrawableRect.height() / mBitmapHeight;
                dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
            } else {
                scale = mDrawableRect.width() / mBitmapWidth;
                dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
            }

            mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth);
            break;
        case CENTER_INSIDE:
            mShaderMatrix.set(null);

            if (mBitmapWidth <= mBounds.width() && mBitmapHeight <= mBounds.height()) {
                scale = 1.0f;
            } else {
                scale = Math.min(mBounds.width() / mBitmapWidth, mBounds.height() / mBitmapHeight);
            }

            dx = (int) ((mBounds.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);
            dy = (int) ((mBounds.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);

            mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            mShaderMatrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

            mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
            mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect.left + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.top + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.right
                    - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.bottom - mBorderWidth);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mDrawableRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            break;
        case FIT_CENTER:
            mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
            mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect.left + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.top + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.right
                    - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.bottom - mBorderWidth);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mDrawableRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            break;
        case FIT_END:
            mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.END);
            mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect.left + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.top + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.right
                    - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.bottom - mBorderWidth);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mDrawableRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            break;
        case FIT_START:
            mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
            mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
            mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect.left + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.top + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.right
                    - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.bottom - mBorderWidth);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mDrawableRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            break;
        case FIT_XY:
        default:
            mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
            mDrawableRect.set(0 + mBorderWidth, 0 + mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth,
                    mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth);
            mShaderMatrix.set(null);
            mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mDrawableRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            break;
        }

        mBorderRect.inset(mBorderWidth / 2, mBorderWidth / 2);

        mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(final Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

        mBounds.set(bounds);

        updateShaderMatrix();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {

        if (mOval) {
            if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                canvas.drawOval(mBorderRect, mBorderPaint);
                canvas.drawOval(mDrawableRect, mBitmapPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawOval(mDrawableRect, mBitmapPaint);
            }
        } else {
            if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(mBorderRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mBorderPaint);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawableRect, Math.max(mCornerRadius - mBorderWidth, 0),
                        Math.max(mCornerRadius - mBorderWidth, 0), mBitmapPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawableRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mBitmapPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(final int alpha) {
        mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(final ColorFilter cf) {
        mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public float getCornerRadius() {
        return mCornerRadius;
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setCornerRadius(final float radius) {
        mCornerRadius = radius;
        return this;
    }

    public float getBorderWidth() {
        return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setBorderWidth(final int width) {
        mBorderWidth = width;
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
        return this;
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
        return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setBorderColor(final int color) {
        return setBorderColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
    }

    public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
        return mBorderColor;
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setBorderColors(final ColorStateList colors) {
        mBorderColor = colors != null ? colors : ColorStateList.valueOf(0);
        mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(), DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isOval() {
        return mOval;
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setOval(final boolean oval) {
        mOval = oval;
        return this;
    }

    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return mScaleType;
    }

    public RoundedDrawable setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType == null) {
            scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_XY;
        }
        if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
            mScaleType = scaleType;
            updateShaderMatrix();
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

**attr.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="RoundedImageView">
    <attr name="corner_radius" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="round_background" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="android:scaleType" />
    <!-- border -->
    <attr name="border_width" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```