# clippath with smooth edges android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

hi everybody I have a custom view that in it I use clippath for clip a circle this is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(min,min,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
Path path2=new Path();
path2.addCircle(x0, y0,r2,Path.Direction.CCW);
c.clipPath(path2,Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
paint.setColor(0xFF09103e);
c.drawCircle(x0,y0,r1,paint);
```

my problem is that when i draw my circle it isnt smooth in edges of its inside where it cliped by other circle.

Comment: use `Paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)`; to draw the smooth edge see if this solve the issue ......

Comment: it dont work.I set  setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG) and paint.setAntiAlias(true); but it dont work still @BBdev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find my answer.I cant smooth path cliped by `setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)` or `paint.setAntiAlias(true);` but i can  try to draw the path on top of the bitmap as a blurred transparent with `paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));` (or was it DST_OUT?)

Comment: check this answer for full picture http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android