# Android how to make this UI

Tags: android, user-interface

Hello guy I have one UI to make in android,but I am not sure in what component to describe it.
Any ideas how to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

2 ImageButtons, a [circular ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android), perhaps one more for that gray dash on the right of the avatar, put everything in a RelativeLayout, I guess.

I've never made such UI, but using my tiny little brain, first I would identify the need for components (see above) and then ask google how I make e.g. a circle shaped ImageView. Google is "clever", you only have to be able to make up some search keywords. I am pretty sure 99% of android code issues are covered on the internet, you just need to find them, instead of wanting people to do it for you.

Comment: Dont attack I just asked how to make, where you saw do it for me !?,I have done it already.

Comment: I didn't mean it bad. You can solve most of your development issues on your own in minutes, if you identify the problem and use a search engine. Most users will ignore questions where the OP just seems to be "lazy".