# How to fill the drawable region in an imageView with another drawable?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-bitmap

so I'm trying to find the region of the current image in the ImageView and fill that region with a different image. Here is the original image [Empty Circle inside an imageView](http://www.intheheavens.org/images/500px-Circle_-_black_simple.svg%5B1%5D.png). The imageView has a drawable of a circle inside. Then I'm trying to make it into something like this [Circle filled with image inside an ImageView](http://us.123rf.com/450wm/iimages/iimages1304/iimages130400939/18983271-illustration-of-a-circle-with-leaves-inside-on-a-white-background.jpg) when a user chooses an image. I don't want to manually Photoshop a circle image. I am just hoping to fill the region with another image. I have tried `SRC_IN` method from `AlphaComposite`, but for android, I can't convert from `BitMap` to `graphics2D`. If anyone knows how to solve this using the `BitmapFactory` in android, I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16208365/2556111

Comment: Hi ramaral, thanks for the link, but in the link, it uses the `Canvas` to draw a circle region then uses `canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);` to draw the `ImageView` with a bitmap inside. While this method would work for a easily defined shape. What I am looking for will be flexible to different shapes (not exactly easy to draw). The circle image I have above is simpliy an example. I am looking for the method of "filling existing drawable image with new drawable image" instead. And not reshaping `ImageView'. I appreciate your help though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution besides Bitmaps, may be too simple for whatever you are trying to achieve otherwise I think it would have occurred to you. I'm just pointing it out in case you have "code blindness" and are trying to over-engineer the solution because you've worked on it for too long (we've all done it)

It is to have that circle/shape image saved as a png with the area you want filled being transparent then set it as the drawable for an ImageView (etc.) then in a RelativeLayout lay this view over the image you want to fill the area and apply a transparent background to the shape view OR simply set the fill image as the background for the shape view.

Comment: Yes, but if I make the shape transparent, I would need the `getTransparentRegion()`. According to the documents, this method call was added since API 1. It is defaulted to return null. If ever I would want to use this method for the `Drawable` class, I would need to override it and provide a method myself to return the bitmap region which is transparent. I have gone over some of the similar problems but would not find something that can perform this operation well (others' method may only discover a portion of the transparent region). Thanks.