# How to modify image appearance in Image View?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview

In my app I am getting image from URL and showing in an ImageView. I get a circle shape(blue color) image which is in a square(white color) background. I want to show my image just as a circle ..How to remove or hide the extra white color in that image within my app?

Below is the image for reference:[image]

Comment: set imageview background as `transparent` and set your image into src

Comment: If the white is part of the image, I don't think you can do something about that.

Comment: Yes. That white is a part of the image.

Comment: Set background transparent or null for imageview and set your image for src.

Comment: Transparent as well as null doesn't make any change here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first remove the white part of image in an image editor like Photoshop or Gimp. Making background transparent won't work because white part is not background, It's in image.

Alternatively, You can create a round Imageview if you want your square images to be shown as circular (e.g. profile pictures on Google+). There is a working code snippet here for rounded ImageView [How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android)

Alternatively, if you don't want to use this snippet, you can use a library that will make it easy to create rounded ImageViews. see this 
https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView‎