# Android drawable shape in xml - Create a transparent circle in a square

Tags: android, android-xml, android-shape

Is there a way to subtract or "cut out" a shape from another shape in xml? I'd like to create a white square with a transparent circular hole in the center... mainly because I don't want to do a bitmap manipulation to make a circular image :).

Yes, I know this solution ([How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android)) exists.

[image]

Comment: Try using [Path FillType even_odd](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/Path.FillType.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot subtract part of a drawable, but you can do a little hack creating a circle that as the same color of your activity background and put it on top of your square using a FrameLayout.