# android circular image view, adding a border

Tags: java, android

I have this code, which draws a circular image of the artist currently playing in my android app.

```
package com.myradio.aacplay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewRounded extends ImageView {

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewRounded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();

        int scaledWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int scaledHeight = getMeasuredHeight();

        Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
        if (scaledWidth == fullSizeBitmap.getWidth()
                && scaledHeight == fullSizeBitmap.getHeight()) {
            mScaledBitmap = fullSizeBitmap;
        } else {
            mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(fullSizeBitmap,
                    scaledWidth, scaledHeight, true /* filter */);
        }

        // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

        // Bitmap roundBitmap = getRoundedCornerBitmap(getContext(),
        // mScaledBitmap, 10, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, false, false,
        // false, false);
        // canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircledBitmap(mScaledBitmap);

        canvas.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Context context, Bitmap input,
            int pixels, int w, int h, boolean squareTL, boolean squareTR,
            boolean squareBL, boolean squareBR) {

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density;

        final int color = 0xff424242;

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        // make sure that our rounded corner is scaled appropriately
        final float roundPx = pixels * densityMultiplier;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        // draw rectangles over the corners we want to be square
        if (squareTL) {
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w / 2, h / 2, paint);
        }
        if (squareTR) {
            canvas.drawRect(w / 2, 0, w, h / 2, paint);
        }
        if (squareBL) {
            canvas.drawRect(0, h / 2, w / 2, h, paint);
        }
        if (squareBR) {
            canvas.drawRect(w / 2, h / 2, w, h, paint);
        }

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(input, 0, 0, paint);

        return output;
    }

    Bitmap getCircledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);






        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        int color = Color.BLUE;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);

//      canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);



        return result;
    }

}
```

and my xml view code:

```
<com.radio.myradio.ImageViewRounded
        android:id="@+id/imagine"
        android:src="@drawable/zupi"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

It works fine, but my problem is that i can't/don't know how to add a white border to the circular view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [create circular image view in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android)

Answer (score 5):

You can try using this [CircularImageView](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) I made. It's easy to use and supports custom borders.

Comment: nice one, I can vouch for this

Comment: Good, but has an issue with `android:scaleType="center"`

Comment: With all scaleTypes

Answer (score 1):

Dude here is the solution..

https://github.com/MostafaGazar/CustomShapeImageView
For more detail
https://coderwall.com/p/hmzf4w

Use this library u will find the circular shape in this library and also easy use.

U can also make your custom shape to this library like cloud etc.
this library supports SVG file format and they made the SVG file of Rounded corner Imageview.

Just use and let me know if there is any problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw circle behinde your Bitmap?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, imageRadius+borderSize, paint);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem with rounded image , i tried adding background to imageview and giving it padding but it didn't work , so i ended up using [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView). The usage is pretty simple and it works perfectly