# How to create Image effect and Imageview Round corner in android

Tags: image-processing, imageview, background-image, rounding, effect

[image]

How to make background image effect and round corner imageview in android?

Comment: Follow [this](http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/) for blur effect and [this](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) for circular imageView.

Answer (score 1):

i found this page for blurring : http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/07/gaussian-blur-imagebitmap-in-imageview.html and for cicular image [How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android)

Comment: Thanks but backgound image is not blur as picture.