# How to create round corner image using volley library android

Tags: android, android-volley, networkimageview

I am getting image urls from server with square shape I have to make it to rounded corner images.Actually I am using volley library ,I know how to create round corner images using universal image loader and picasso libraries.In volley library I am setting image in network imageview like setimageUrl please help me

```
 holder.ivImage.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Comment: Volley is networking library and has nothing to do with manipulating images. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-circular-image-view-in-android

Comment: @mata yes, but if the user is using NetworkImageView from the volley library, He needs to know how to manipulate the image. The answer you linked uses "getDrawable()" in its "onDraw()" to access the image, but the drawable is only set if the image was set from a drawable resource. In NetworkImageView, only an image url is set, and when the image finishes downloading, "setBitmap" is called to set the image and the drawable does not get set.

Answer (score 19):

I found an source code which makes imageview rounded shape e.g. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView. **which was extending imageview, I just make it extend NetworkImageView**. Everything working fine for me. If you don't want to use above circular image view, you have to extend NetworkImageView class and customize to meet your needs.

Comment: How was this done? Did you just copy and paste the code into your project? If so, how did you reference your class in the layout xml?

Comment: I copied the code. I referenced like this in layout <com.gwf.circleview.app.view.Card           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: This worked great, thanks Prashanth. I then had to add an attribute xml and site it using custom:attr_name="attr_value" in my XML

Comment: If it is really helped you then please up vote the answer.

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar Wow, I was using [Volley's NetworkImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java) and wanted it to be circle. I use this class and `extends` it to `NetworkImageView` instead of `ImageView` and it worked! Thanks man.
.
You can accept this answer, may be you can give a try like I did. @Peter

Comment: Be aware that CircleImageView only support CENTER_CROP. and we cant change it. It is suitable for profile images but not helpful if you have any other requirement.

Comment: Could you please that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35124025/extending-circle-image-to-network-image-volley

Answer (score 9):

you need to extend **NetworkImageView** class and create own view

**Java**: CircularNetworkImageView

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;



public class CircularNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    Context mContext;

    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        if(bm==null) return;
        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),
                getCircularBitmap(bm)));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a circular bitmap and uses whichever dimension is smaller to determine the width
     * <br/>Also constrains the circle to the leftmost part of the image
     *
     * @param bitmap
     * @return bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        if(bitmap.getWidth()>bitmap.getHeight())
            width = bitmap.getHeight();
        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, width);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = width / 2;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<com.example.own.CircularNetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>
```

**Usage:**

```
    CircularNetworkImageView image = (CircularNetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    private ImageLoader netImageLoader=AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    image.setImageUrl("imageurl", netImageLoader);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom class which extends NetworkImageView(Volley).

[Code](https://github.com/kamilZ/CircledNetworkImageView/blob/master/CircledNetworkImageView)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageContainer;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.ImageListener;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 * Handles fetching an image from a URL as well as the life-cycle of the
 * associated request.
 */
public class CircledNetworkImageView extends ImageView {
    public boolean mCircled;

    /** The URL of the network image to load */
    private String mUrl;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used as a placeholder until the network image is loaded.
     */
    private int mDefaultImageId;

    /**
     * Resource ID of the image to be used if the network response fails.
     */
    private int mErrorImageId;

    /** Local copy of the ImageLoader. */
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    /** Current ImageContainer. (either in-flight or finished) */
    private ImageContainer mImageContainer;

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircledNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Sets URL of the image that should be loaded into this view. Note that calling this will
     * immediately either set the cached image (if available) or the default image specified by
     * {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} on the view.
     *
     * NOTE: If applicable, {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setDefaultImageResId(int)} and
     * {@link CircledNetworkImageView#setErrorImageResId(int)} should be called prior to calling
     * this function.
     *
     * @param url The URL that should be loaded into this ImageView.
     * @param imageLoader ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
     */
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary(false);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the default image resource ID to be used for this view until the attempt to load it
     * completes.
     */
    public void setDefaultImageResId(int defaultImage) {
        mDefaultImageId = defaultImage;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the error image resource ID to be used for this view in the event that the image
     * requested fails to load.
     */
    public void setErrorImageResId(int errorImage) {
        mErrorImageId = errorImage;
    }

    /**
     * Loads the image for the view if it isn't already loaded.
     * @param isInLayoutPass True if this was invoked from a layout pass, false otherwise.
     */
    private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        boolean isFullyWrapContent = getLayoutParams() != null
                && getLayoutParams().height == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                && getLayoutParams().width == ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        // if the view's bounds aren't known yet, and this is not a wrap-content/wrap-content
        // view, hold off on loading the image.
        if (width == 0 && height == 0 && !isFullyWrapContent) {
            return;
        }

        // if the URL to be loaded in this view is empty, cancel any old requests and clear the
        // currently loaded image.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mUrl)) {
            if (mImageContainer != null) {
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                mImageContainer = null;
            }
            setImageBitmap(null);
            return;
        }

        // if there was an old request in this view, check if it needs to be canceled.
        if (mImageContainer != null && mImageContainer.getRequestUrl() != null) {
            if (mImageContainer.getRequestUrl().equals(mUrl)) {
                // if the request is from the same URL, return.
                return;
            } else {
                // if there is a pre-existing request, cancel it if it's fetching a different URL.
                mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
                setImageBitmap(null);
            }
        }

        // The pre-existing content of this view didn't match the current URL. Load the new image
        // from the network.
        ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                        // If this was an immediate response that was delivered inside of a layout
                        // pass do not set the image immediately as it will trigger a requestLayout
                        // inside of a layout. Instead, defer setting the image by posting back to
                        // the main thread.
                        if (isImmediate && isInLayoutPass) {
                            post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    onResponse(response, false);
                                }
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                            setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                        } else if (mDefaultImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mDefaultImageId);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // update the ImageContainer to be the new bitmap container.
        mImageContainer = newContainer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        loadImageIfNecessary(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        if (mImageContainer != null) {
            // If the view was bound to an image request, cancel it and clear
            // out the image from the view.
            mImageContainer.cancelRequest();
            setImageBitmap(null);
            // also clear out the container so we can reload the image if necessary.
            mImageContainer = null;
        }
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageResource(resId);
    }

    /**
     * In case the bitmap is manually changed, we make sure to
     * circle it on the next onDraw
     */
    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        mCircled = false;
        super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    /**
     * We want to make sure that the ImageView has the same height and width
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable != null) {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int diw = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            if (diw > 0) {
                int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / diw;
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
            } else
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Let's circle the image
        if ( !mCircled && getDrawable() != null) {
            Drawable d = getDrawable();
            try {
                //We use reflection here in case that the drawable isn't a
                //BitmapDrawable but it contains a public getBitmap method.
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) d.getClass().getMethod("getBitmap").invoke(d);
                if(bitmap != null){
                    Bitmap circleBitmap = getCircleBitmap(bitmap);
                    setImageBitmap(circleBitmap);
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                //Seems like the current drawable is not a BitmapDrawable or
                //that is doesn't have a public getBitmap() method.
            }

            //Mark as circled even if it failed, because if it fails once,
            //It will fail again.
            mCircled = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * Method used to circle a bitmap.
     *
     * @param bitmap The bitmap to circle
     * @return The circled bitmap
     */
    public static Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int size = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(size,
                size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        BitmapShader shader;
        shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(shader);

        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0 ,size,size);
        int radius = size/2;
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, radius,radius, paint);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes, but just the *essential* parts.

Comment: Need to include how its using too?

Comment: That would be nice, but the current code is very long and contains a lot of mostly-irrelevant support code; cutting it down to the key sections would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

you can use CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/spacing_tiny">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
    ...
    />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

- In the volley library, copy the class called "NetworkImageView" and name it "NetworkImageViewCircle".

  ```
  private void setAnimateImageBitmap(final Bitmap bitmap, boolean fadeIn) {

  final Bitmap bmp;

  bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
          bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap,
          BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP,
          BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);

  float radius = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight()) / 5;
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
  Paint paint = new Paint();
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setShader(shader);

  RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
  .
  .
  .
  ```

This made the trick for me. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/container"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="80dp"
       app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
       app:cardElevation="0dp" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the output]I am able to make circler NetworkImage without extending NetworkImage

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/myCardVi"
                android:layout_width="188dp"
                android:layout_height="188dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:alpha="0.95"
                android:elevation="12dp"
                android:innerRadius="0dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"

                app:cardCornerRadius="94dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/myCardVie"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:alpha="0.95"
                    android:elevation="12dp"
                    android:innerRadius="0dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"

                    app:cardCornerRadius="89dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">


                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="178dp"
                        android:layout_height="178dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"

                        />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -3):

Volley has nothing to do with round corner image .

You can make a simple circle with white border and transparent content with shape.

// res/drawable/circle.xml

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:innerRadius="0dp"
         android:shape="ring"
         android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
         android:useLevel="false" >
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

      <stroke
           android:width="10dp"
           android:color="@android:color/white" />
  </shape>
```

Then make a layerlist drawable and put it as background to your networkimageview.

```
// res/drawable/img.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>

</layer-list>
```

and put it as background to your networkimageview.

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
    android:id="@+id/networkImageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/img"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

You'll have something like that.

[image]

Comment: your hardcoding the ic_launcher.png in the img.xm, we need to round the image downloaded from the network