# In Android ListView what is this the proper way to load rounded images along with text?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to create a ListView which contains a simple rounded image and textView along with it ,to achive rounded image i have created a function to make it round and since i get the image url from json object as httpurl i have used another function to get bitmap from it.. but looks something is seriously wrong because the ListView is taking too long to load and its even freezing when i scroll.

public class MyImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<UserInfo> values;

String mother_name;

String mother_image;

public MyImageListAdapter(Activity atvt, Context context,
        ArrayList<UserInfo> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.my_list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_name_fragment, parent,
            false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

    textView.setText(((UserInfo) values.get(position)).getUserName());

    String motherImageURl = ((UserInfo) values.get(position))
            .getPrifileImageUr();

    mother_name = ((UserInfo) values.get(position)).getUserName();
    mother_image = motherImageURl;

    Bitmap bm = getBitmapFromHttpURL(motherImageURl);
    Bitmap bm1 = getRoundedCornerBitmapWithBorderSmall(bm, 2);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm1);

    rowView.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);

    return rowView;
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromHttpURL(String src) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> ac = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                myBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 200, 200,
                        true);

                return myBitmap;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

        }
    };
    try {
        bitmap = ac.execute(src).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,200,200, true);

    return bitmap;

}

public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmapWithBorderSmall(Bitmap bitmap,
        int border) {

    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();

    // if(w>50 || h>50){w=50;h=50;}

    int a, b;

    System.out.println("-------" + bitmap.getByteCount() + "--" + h + "---"
            + w);

    int radius = Math.min(h / 2, w / 2);
    a = Math.max(w, h);
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(a, a, Config.ARGB_8888);

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(output);
    c.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);

    p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));

    c.drawBitmap(bitmap, 4, 4, p);
    p.setXfermode(null);
    p.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#61445C"));
    p.setStrokeWidth(border);
    c.drawCircle((w / 2) + 4, (h / 2) + 4, radius, p);
    // output = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 200, 200, true);
    // output=getResizedBitmap(output, 200,200) ;
    // Bitmap yourBitmap;
    output = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 100, 100, true);
    return output;

}
```

}

Comment: Use ViewHodler concept to make the listview scroll smoother...

Comment: you can use universal image loader to load and cache the images in more quicker and easier way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library for loading images directly from URL with single line of code.

For making image rounded corner you can refer my answer [How to create round corner image using volley library android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283373/how-to-create-round-corner-image-using-volley-library-android/25284198#25284198)

And also one suggestion for your networking, use Volley library for it . It is for faster and better networking.