# How to create rounded corner image using volley library android

Tags: android, imageview, android-volley

I am getting image urls from server with square shape I have to make it to rounded corner images.Actually I am using volley library ,I know how to create round corner images using universal image loader and picasso libraries.In volley library I am setting image in network imageview like setimageUrl please help me

```
holder.ivImage.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
```

Comment: use this [Library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).

Comment: please read question(sorry if question is not clear) clearly. I am using com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView then how can I use de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an source code which makes imageview rounded shape e.g. https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView. which was extending imageview, I just make it extend NetworkImageView. Everything working fine for me.

Comment: It is working well you can find same question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283373/how-to-create-round-corner-image-using-volley-library-android/30054566#30054566

Answer (score -1):

use [RoundedBitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html) to make a rounded image, this way it does not matter what kind of imageview you use

Answer (score -1):

This project could be useful for you [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)