# Extending Circle image to Network Image - volley

Tags: android

I need to extend the  de.hdodenhof:circleimageview to NetworkImage with volley. Therefore I copied the CircleImageView and extended to NetworkImage and called from my class. But it did not applied circle image, and also does not show the image at all.

I am working on the **header.xml**

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer"
        />
```

I changed from

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView
```

to

```
public class CircleImageView extends com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
```

and in the **xml**

```
<com.example.xx.xx.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />
```

but the following works with default ImageView extension

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="76dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile"
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />
```

Comment: CircleImageView extends by NetworkImageView in place of ImageView

Comment: yes that is what I did.

Comment: Then what the problem

Comment: It does not apply to my image. I do not even see the image at all.

Comment: do you able to run the code if yes then give your logcat?

Comment: I could able to run the code, it is successful, no error.

Comment: might be like for updated circle imageview code its not working. I am not sure.

Comment: how did you called the circaleimageview in your class? imageview,NetworkImageview or CircleImageview?

Comment: I am using navigationView,  see my updated question. In the navigationdrawerk, there is header layout.

Comment: By the way, when I open the xml, it does not even show the profile image in the designer. But If I used the default version of that class using grade, it applies in real time, you will see the circle image in the designer.

Comment: Actually root of my problem is networkImageView does not show source drawable in the designer. How could I able to make it work?

Comment: @hotspring setDefaultImageResId() for this ImageView programmatically. It'll work