# How can I make a circular menu icon? Please see details

Tags: android, material-design, android-menu, android-icons

I'm developing a **material design** app & I want that the menu icon on toolbar should appear as a **circular image** instead of **rectangular image**.

Here is the screenshot:

Look at the **menu icon**, it is appearing as a **rectangle**, but I want it to be **circular**.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a circularimageview library

Comment: Can you show a picture of the circular menu button?

Comment: @TimCastelijns but how can I use it to change the layout of menu icon?

Comment: if the libraries didn't help you ....see the answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166664/how-to-show-a-circular-logo-in-action-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for android to make the photo circular ....
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView
that's the link ....try it :)

Edit:
or you can use this library :
https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

Comment: The problem is that how can I use these libraries to change menu's icon's layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this websit to return the circle icon:

[Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=circle&backColor=ffffff%2C100&effects=none)

And then include it in the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a circular icon using the icon generator tool (Android Asset Studio) in 2 steps.

1. Feed it the icon image with relevant options chosen and generate a circular launcher icon using the link below.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

2. Then use the circular launcher icon generated above (xxxhdpi format) and feed it for the link below to generate an action bar icon.

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is not what I want. Actually that 'Icon' will be the 'profile pic' set up by the user. So, I want that every pic should become circular there.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the tutorial from several different providers as follows which are recommended by SO

[Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)
[Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)
[AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

All of them have great examples and source code to help you out

Comment: this is not what I want. Actually that 'Icon' will be the 'profile pic' set up by the user. So, I want that every pic should become circular there.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 steps:

**1. Create menu item**

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile_menu_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/prof"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="MenuTitle"/>
</menu>
```

**2. Retrieve menu item**

```
private MenuItem mProfileMenuItem;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mProfileMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.profile_menu_item);
        return true;
    }
```

**3. Crop bitmap into round bitmap**

```
public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    // canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    //Bitmap _bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(output, 60, 60, false);
    //return _bmp;
    return output;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12089127/578309)

**4. Download an url image as a bitmap, and crop**

```
new Handler().post(() -> Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).asBitmap().load(url).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            if (mProfileMenuItem == null) return;
            mProfileMenuItem.setIcon(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), Utils.getCroppedBitmap(resource)));
        }
    }));
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41804371/578309)