# How to use CircleImageView with Volley's NetworkImageView?

Tags: android, imageview, geometry, networkimageview

I need to get circle images from rectangular/square images taken from network. In my application I get images with Volley's NetworkImageView. I found that fantastic library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView but I don't understand how I can use it with NetworkImageView.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Look this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849911/rounded-imageview-for-image-that-loaded-from-web/29850429#29850429

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create round corner image using volley library android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25283373/how-to-create-round-corner-image-using-volley-library-android)

Answer (score 1):

Check this Class

```
public class CirculaireNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    private int borderWidth;
    private int canvasSize;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;

    public CirculaireNetworkImageView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CirculaireNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.actionButtonStyle);
    }

    public CirculaireNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        this.requestLayout();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public void addShadow() {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // load the bitmap
        image = drawableToBitmap(getDrawable());

        // init shader
        if (image != null) {

            canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
            if(canvas.getHeight()<canvasSize)
                canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();

            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvasSize, canvasSize, false), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            paint.setShader(shader);

            // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
            // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
            // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
            int circleCenter = (canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2;
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2) + borderWidth - 4.0f, paintBorder);
            canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, ((canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2) - 4.0f, paint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // The parent has determined an exact size for the child.
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child.
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight) {
        int result = 0;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }

    public Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code of the NetworkImageView [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/d62a616ebca5bfa4f9ec5517208e13f2d501b69a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/NetworkImageView.java). Modify it to extend your "CircleImageView" instead of the normal ImageView and you are done.