# round profile image in android

Tags: android, rounding, profile, profile-picture

I use the below code for making round profile picture in android

http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/10/android-custom-shape-imageview-rounded.html

But in my main activity I used ListFragment instead of Activity

```
imageViewRound = ImageView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_round);
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.noimage_square);
imageViewRound.setImageBitmap(icon);
```

I'm getting this error

```
05-15 12:21:27.359: E/AndroidRuntime(25107): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: see this it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android parentView might be null post your full code

Comment: @Nidhin .. Check my below solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try these***

```
 com.androidhub4you.crop.RoundedImageView imageViewRound =(com.androidhub4you.crop.RoundedImageView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_round);
```

Comment: The error is still exist.

Comment: Same error occurred or different one??

Comment: Same error. 05-15 13:58:32.132: E/AndroidRuntime(29214): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.toptechinfo.chachalanka.RoundedImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference

Comment: Use these  "imageViewRound .setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bit‌​map)" instead of "com.toptechinfo.chachalanka.RoundedImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bit‌​map)'"

Comment: android.graphics.Bitmap cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Are you not using these lines of code in yours program

"Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.noimage_square);
imageViewRound.setImageBitmap(icon);"