# Android About Region and Touch

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I'm developing an image-processing program. And i'm stuck here.
I have an image like this:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/4kobhtllj/]

I drew a closed line (path) by finger. Now, I want to get all points in the closed-region cut out from the image. Is there any algorithm or method?

Answer (score 0):

[How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android)

this may help you.
it user drawCircle() to crop a circle,   maybe drawPath() can crop a region...