# How to add a circle shape to an ImageView programmatically Android

Tags: android, imageview

I want to add a circle black shape to the circle ImageView I have.

I want something like this :

[image]

here is my code to make the ImageView circle :

```
 private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = Color.RED;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    bitmap.recycle();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: have u seen this https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use CircleImageView:

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your images rounded, then use RoundedImageView as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android#answer-16208548).