# CircularImageView and API 16: NullPointerException error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview

I was testing my app on different APIs and it seems to work on API 17 till 23 but I found in API 16, I cannot load my customview. I just want to display a photo in a circle and I have obtained the code for the customview from this thread: [How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/create-a-circular-image-view-in-android)

My code is pasted here:

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {

    public CircularImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CircularImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        int w = getWidth();

        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
        canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;

        if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
            float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
            float factor = smallest / radius;
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
        } else {
            sbmp = bmp;
        }

        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
```

This is the logcat:

> 01-09 15:09:51.185 2119-2119/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                        at com.example.simon.customshapes.CircularImageView.getCroppedBitmap(CircularImageView.java:59)
>                                                        at com.example.simon.customshapes.CircularImageView.onDraw(CircularImageView.java:51)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13458)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:3588)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
>                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:3097)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2806)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
>                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2262)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1077)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13461)
>                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12409)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2799)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12407)
>                                                        at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12453)
>                                                        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13182)
>                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2929)
>                                                     at a

Is there a reason why I cannot draw a circular imageview in Android API 16?

Comment: Plz use CircleImageView https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to convert your drawable to a bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then instead of using in the original code, the following line:

```
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

Use this instead:

```
Bitmap b = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
```

Then it will run without error.

Answer (score 1):

Well since your bitmap is null and the drawable isn't the only place the error can be at is within [`copy(Bitmap, boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copy(android.graphics.Bitmap.Config,%20boolean)).

If you look at the documentation

> If the conversion is not supported, or the allocator fails, then this returns NULL.

Try using a smaller image, since this can be a sign of Low Memory. You should also add some guard against the possible null value returned, e.g. just drawing the normal bitmap in that case.

Comment: The bitmaps I'm loading are really small though. Nothing is greater than 100kb, most are under 50kb.

Comment: From what I see the error comes from that line. It could still be the bitmap transform being failing, but I would not know why :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use MLRoundedImageView for circular imageview. 
**MLRoundedImageView.java**

```
public class MLRoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MLRoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;

    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
}
```

Then use like this in layout

```
   <com.yourproject.MLRoundedImagView
  Layout properties here />
```

Then in your activity

```
MLRoundedImagView imageview = (MLRoundedImagView) findViewbyId(R.id.imageview);
```

Comment: Sorry - not sure how this answers my question as the code inside your class is the same as the code in my class. I can create the circle - i just cannot create the circle in API 16.