# Fetch Google Play Games profile image and make it circled

Tags: android, google-play-games

I want to fetch the profile image from google play games which is working with this method:

```
public void loadPlayerImage() {
            ImageView playerImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playerImage);
            Player me = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient);
            ImageManager mgr = ImageManager.create(this);
            mgr.loadImage(playerImage, me.getIconImageUri());
}
```

But when I try to make it circled with this library it does not show the image:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

How can I circle the profile image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [code](https://ruibm.com/2009/06/16/rounded-corner-bitmaps-on-android/) as a helper within an `ImageHelper` class and extend it to pass in the amount of feathering you need for a given image.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
  Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
      bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

  final int color = 0xff424242;
  final Paint paint = new Paint();
  final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
  final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
  final float roundPx = 12;

  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
  paint.setColor(color);
  canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

  return output;
}
```

You can also check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16208548/5832311):

> I too needed a rounded ImageView, I used the below code, you can
>   modify it accordingly:
>
> ```
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.graphics.Bitmap;
> import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
> import android.graphics.Canvas;
> import android.graphics.Color;
> import android.graphics.Paint;
> import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
> import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
> import android.graphics.Rect;
> import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
> import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
> import android.util.AttributeSet;
> import android.widget.ImageView;
>
> public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
>
>   public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
>       super(context);
>   }
>
>   public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>       super(context, attrs);
>   }
>
>   public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>   }
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>
>       Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
>
>       if (drawable == null) {
>           return;
>       }
>
>       if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
>           return;
>       }
>       Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
>       Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
>
>       int w = getWidth();
>       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
>       int h = getHeight();
>
>       Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
>       canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
>
>   }
>
>   public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
>       Bitmap sbmp;
>
>       if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
>           float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
>           float factor = smallest / radius;
>           sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
>                   (int) (bmp.getWidth() / factor),
>                   (int) (bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
>       } else {
>           sbmp = bmp;
>       }
>
>       Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius, Config.ARGB_8888);
>       Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
>
>       final String color = "#BAB399";
>       final Paint paint = new Paint();
>       final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);
>
>       paint.setAntiAlias(true);
>       paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
>       paint.setDither(true);
>       canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
>       paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
>       canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.7f,
>               radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
>       paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
>       canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);
>
>       return output;
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Here are some related SO posts which might help:

- [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)
- [How to create a circular ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/how-to-create-a-circular-imageview-in-android)