# how to make my listview image round and add the fixed icon in android json?

Tags: android, json, listview, circleimage

I am trying to make my images from listview round but its not happening ..i endup getting the image like this[image]

but i want my listview image like this,
[image]

Here is SumMenu activity:

```
public class SubMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "id";
    static String COUNTRY = "name";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String status="";
    static String FLAG = "image";
    Integer i = 1;
    String _stringVal;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
   /* final int Pizza = 0; //should be equal to the index in your array.
    final int Pasta = 1;
    final int Lasagna = 2;
    final int Salad =3 ;
    final int Breakfast = 4;
    final int Beverages= 5;
    final int Soup = 6;

    final int SpecialOffer =7;*/



    private static String url_create_book = "http://cloud....com/broccoli/creatinfo.php";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_menu);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        String SelectedId = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Get the view from listview_main.xml

        // Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        // @Override
        //  protected void onPreExecute() {
        //  super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        //   mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SubMenu.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        //   mProgressDialog.setTitle("Categories of Main categories.....");
        // Set progressdialog message
        //  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        //  mProgressDialog.show();
        // }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonarray = JsonFunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://cloud..com/broccoli/menu_typeitem.php?id=" + getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("name", jsonobject.getString("name"));
                    map.put("image", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(SubMenu.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            // Close the progressdialog
            // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long rowId) {
                                some coding....
                               }
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                   View view, int pos, long id) {
            //  Toast.makeText(SubMenu.this,"The planet is " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

here is listview adapter:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        TextView population;
        CircleImageView image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent, false);
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
       // id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idq);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type1);


        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        image = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subimg);
      //  icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
      //  id.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.RANK));
        name.setText(resultp.get(SubMenu.COUNTRY));

        // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
        // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), image);
      //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), icon);
        // Capture ListView item click
        /**itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        resultp = data.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
        // Pass all data country
        intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
        // Pass all data population
        intent.putExtra("population",resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
        // Pass all data flag
        intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
        // Start SingleItemView Class
        context.startActivity(intent);

        }
        });*/
        return itemView;
    }
}
```

this is my ImageLoader..

public class ImageLoader {

```
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    // Handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.avatar;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download Images from the Internet
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            // Recommended Size 512
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

this is my  list_item1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/subimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/colorwhite"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />


</LinearLayout>
```

i tried circleImage view and added the library also in my gradle..

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

and i am not getting the fixed plus image also...what to do?

After the @sneha code i am getting like this...how to fix in same line proper way..[image]

Comment: remove your background color from image:


    android:background="@color/colorwhite"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/subimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/plus_image" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Try this code. to add fixed plus image, set a plus image in `drawable` folder with name "`plus_image`". And set the circular image as src

Comment: let me check. Wait for a moment.

Comment: See my edited code. Just change gravity of TextView to layout_gravity. It will give you the result in proper way.

Comment: ok, but if u can see my plus image its little bit cut from right..if i add padding from right then also its d same ...wht to do to show full plus image

Answer (score 1):

try modifying your xml like this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/subimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/colorwhite"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />


</LinearLayout>
```

for circular image view see below

Try using

```
 compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
```

[This](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView) library

```
 <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/photo1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
    app:riv_border_width="2dip"
    app:riv_border_color="#333333"
    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
    app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
    app:riv_oval="true" />
```

or you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208365/how-to-create-a-circular-imageview-in-android)

Comment: how to add that fixed plus image?

Comment: your plus icon not coming because you used match parent, try my xml and see

Comment: its always better to give hard coded values for image views and wrapcontent and weight for other views inside linear layout

Comment: inside linear layour , if 1 child view is using match parent(taking total space) then where will other child views get space?

Comment: when i was trying to replace ur code my plus image is not coming in a sequence..it shud b in proper line but its nt same for all thr rows

Comment: sorry remove weight from plus icon imageview,updated see

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEM HERE**

```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**For @+id/plus Remove**

```
 android:layout_weight
```

You should set **Hard-coded** Size respect to Library

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/subimg"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/colorwhite"
    android:padding="1dp" />
```

Comment: remove `android:layout_weight="3"` and set `android:layout_width=25dp`

Comment: @z.al did you overcome this

Comment: @z.al indeed .problem for your image

Answer (score 1):

1st option is ---- use circleimageview class

```
public class CircleImageView extends NetworkImageView {

    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
    private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

    private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

    private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

    private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
    private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
    private int mBitmapWidth;
    private int mBitmapHeight;

    private float mDrawableRadius;
    private float mBorderRadius;

    private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

    private boolean mReady;
    private boolean mSetupPending;
    private boolean mBorderOverlay;

    public CircleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);

    a.recycle();

    init();
    }

    private void init() {
    super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
    mReady = true;

    if (mSetupPending) {
        setup();
        mSetupPending = false;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
    if (adjustViewBounds) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getDrawable() == null) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
    if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    setup();
    }

    public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = borderColor;
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
    setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
    }

    public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    setup();
    }

    public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
    return mBorderOverlay;
    }

    public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
    if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
    setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    mBitmap = bm;
    setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
    setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
    setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setImageURI(uri);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
    setup();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    if (cf == mColorFilter) {
        return;
    }

    mColorFilter = cf;
    mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
    invalidate();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        return null;
    }
    }

    private void setup() {
    if (!mReady) {
        mSetupPending = true;
        return;
    }

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

    mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

    mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2);

    mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
    if (!mBorderOverlay) {
        mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
    }
    mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2, mDrawableRect.width() / 2);

    updateShaderMatrix();
    invalidate();
    }

    private void updateShaderMatrix() {
    float scale;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;

    mShaderMatrix.set(null);

    if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
        scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
        dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
    } else {
        scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
        dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
    }

    mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
    }

}
```

in xml file use this imageview---

```
<Your_package_name.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_image"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_default
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@android:color/transparent"
        />
```

Define this attribute in `attrs.xml` file

```
 <declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
    <attr name="civ_border_width" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="civ_border_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="civ_border_overlay" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="civ_fill_color" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

2nd option is ,if you load image from server use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(url)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
     .error(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
     .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
     .into(imageview);
```

i have not  comment rights so i edit in my answer

---- you have to follow glide link and follow its step... and then in adapter you have to replace your old code

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG), image);
```

with

```
   Glide.with(this)
     .load(resultp.get(SubMenu.FLAG))
     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
     .error(R.drawable.ic_user_default)
     .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(this))
     .into(image);
```

just try this,,, hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml to display image in circular format. card view will be perfact solution for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:elevation="12dp"
      android:id="@+id/view2"
      app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:innerRadius="0dp"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thicknessRatio="1.9">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/subimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       >
    </ImageView>
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type1"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Add this dependency in gradle file of your application.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.0'
```

Comment: its still the same with square image if i add to background to white then ..otherwise if i removes the background the image is backgroundless so no need to circle..but i want to show it a circle

Comment: you want a white circle at the back of image here is the solution you can check.